# AWS Lambda Python Docker image: timeout

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I am trying to deploy a function that converts strings into vectors to AWS Lambda:

```
def _encode(text: str):
  [<main functionality>]

@lru_cache
def encode(text: str):
    return _encode(text)



def handler(event, context):
    return encode(event["text"])
```

This function works as expected when I call it in the Python shell:

```
import app
app.handler({"text"}, None)

<expected result>
```

The `encode()` functionally actually is complex and requires external dependencies (>1GB) which is why I am going for the Docker image approach as described in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html). This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-python:3.9


# Install requirements
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"


# Copy app
COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

Build the Docker image and run it:

```
$ docker build -t my-image:latest .
[...]
Successfully built xxxx
Successfully tagged my-image:latest

$ docker run -p 9000:8080 my-image:latest 
time="2021-10-07T10:12:13.165" level=info msg="exec '/var/runtime/bootstrap' (cwd=/var/task, handler=)"
```

So I try to test the function locally with curl, following the [testing documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-test.html), and it succeeds

I've pushed the image to AWS ECR and created a Kambda function. I've created a test in the AWS Lambda console:

```
{
  "text": "doc"
}
```

When I run the test in the AWS Lambda Console, it times out, even after increasing the timeout to 60s. Locally, the function takes less than 1 second to execute.

On AWS Lambda, only the timeout is logged, I don't see how to get to the root cause. How can I debug this? How can I get more useful logs?

Comment: How long does the docker file take to initialize? that can affect the Cold Start of the lambda and can lead to some weird situations if it is an excessively long time

You might try looking into Elastic File System - you can load your python imports there and define a PYTHONPATH for your lambda to reach them

Comment: Locally, it loads within <1s, so that should not contribute to a timeout within 60s. Also, if it was an issue on AWS Lambda it would not explain why I cannot test it locally.

Comment: Locally, I used the wrong port. It should be `docker run -p 9000:8080` (instead of `8000`). However, the behaviour on AWS Lambda does not change, and I cannot get meaningful logs there.

Comment: Looks like loading just takes incredibly long at some occasions. Not sure how to dig deeper into this.

Comment: Yeah. It probably all depends on what resources are available in the backend and we simple users have no involvement there.

Comment: Again tho, look into EFS. You can set up your entire dependency structure to exist there and not be part of your cold starts at all, cause they already exist

Comment: The problem is not loading dependencies, they are all in the container image. The problem is loading a model (which resides inside the image as well) into memory. On a local machine, this takes 3-4 seconds max, but on AWS this seems to take 40-50s on average, but with large margins.

Comment: Yes, but the EFS is a file system. You can put your model there and access it much quicker. Im not sure what format your model is in, but maybe you could pickle it as well to increase load times.

But - as noted - sometimes lambdas are just slow because AWS has its resoruces stretched a little and yours was lower priority.